# ETCD certs data to Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to get my head around how to get prometheus https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/prometheus collect etcd stats. I understand I need to set tls for it, but have a hard time to find good way to do it without manual additional ansible steps. Is there the way I can get etcd certs on worker node and mount them to prometheus pod?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Monitoring External Etcd Cluster With Prometheus Operator](https://jpweber.io/blog/monitoring-external-etcd-cluster-with-prometheus-operator/) you can easily configure Prometheus to scrape metrics from ETCD.

> We can do all of that by creating certs as kubernetes secrets and
>   adding a tlsConfig to our service monitor. Let me walk you through the
>   whole process.

The steps are:

1) Create etcd `service`

2) Create/attach `endpoints` for etcd service

3) Create service monitor with appropriate tlsconfig. below example

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: etcd
  name: etcd
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    port: metrics
    scheme: https
    tlsConfig:
      caFile: /etc/prometheus/secrets/kube-etcd-client-certs/etcd-client-ca.crt
      certFile: /etc/prometheus/secrets/kube-etcd-client-certs/etcd-client.crt
      keyFile: /etc/prometheus/secrets/kube-etcd-client-certs/etcd-client.key
      serverName: etcd-cluster
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: etcd
```

4) Create Etcd Client Certificates

5) Create Kubernetes Secrets along with previously created certificate and key for prometheus and  etcd ca. This will allow prometheus to securely connect to etcd.
Example:

```
kubectl -n monitoring create secret kube-etcd-client-certs --from-file=etcd-client-ca.crt=etcd-client.ca.crt --from-file=etcd-client.crt=etcd-client.crt --from-file=etcd-client.key=etcd-client.key
```

6) Update prometheus.yaml to include there names of the created secrets.

7) delploy etcd-service,servicemonitor and prometheus manifests to cluster

```
kubectl apply -f etcd-service.yaml
kubectl apply -f etcd-serviceMon.yaml
kubectl apply -f prometheus-prometheus.yaml
```

Enjoy